# A unique sequence solution

Tags: number-sequence

Let's have the sequence 127,191,255,319,383,... This sequence is formulated by adding the number 64 to the last term to obtain the new term e.g 127+64=191 and so on. There is another special way to create the same terms of this sequence. The question is, which is this other special way to create the same terms of this sequence?

HINT: If we have the sequence of odd natural numbers 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,....then in a unique way by multiplication and addition we formulate the given sequence 127,191,255,319,383,....

Comment: "another unique" is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: @Bass. I edited the question. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If I take the hint literally, the relationship is 32x+97, but I don't feel it's that special... After all, we can make up infinitely many different properties out of an arithmetic sequence.

Comment: @ Bubbler.191-97=94 the last number is not divisible by 32 As i said on the HINT there is a unique way try again and you mind find it..

Comment: @VassilisParassidis I meant 32x+95, not 97 (messed up -1 with +1).

Comment: @ Bubber. 1795-95=1700  1700/32=53.125  try to find the tenth term of the sequence with your method..

Answer (score 3):

If we firstly

> Convert each number to base 8

Then these numbers are

> Exactly those which end in two 7s (starting at 177) i.e, $$177, 277, 377, 477, \ldots$$

Comment: That can be said for base 4 (ending in 333) and base 2 (ending in 111111) too, which are essentially the same as saying "the numbers 64n+63"...

Comment: The unique answer I am looking for contains the same numbers that are in the sequence.